"ERROR - failed inserting new data: ('HY000', "[HY000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL7008"
can you help me to understand how to avoid this error? This is my code:
conn_test = get_db_connection('liq_test')
cursor_test = conn_test.cursor()
conn = get_db_connection('liq')
cursor = conn.cursor()
output_db = pd.concat([output_db_f,output_db_o]).reset_index(drop=True) 
def fetch_table_colnames(cursor, schema, table):
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_schema = '{schema}' AND table_name = '{table}'")
    return [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]

table='RMSSTRPRI'
table_columns_test = fetch_table_colnames(cursor_test, 'LIQTOOLDEV', table)

for col in table_columns_test:
    if col not in output_db.columns:
        output_db[col] = ''

df_filtered_test = output_db[table_columns_test]
Function to handle database insertion
def insert_data(cursor, conn, table, df_filtered):
    cursor=cursor_test
    conn=conn_test
    df_filtered=df_filtered_test
    table='LIQTOOLDEV.RMSSTRPRI'
    ref_dates = df_filtered['REF_DT'].unique()
    for ref_date in ref_dates:
        try:
            check_query = f"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {table} WHERE REF_DT = ?"
            cursor.execute(check_query, [int(ref_date)])
            count = cursor.fetchone()[0]
            if count > 0:
                delete_query = f"DELETE FROM {table} WHERE REF_DT = ?"
                cursor.execute(delete_query, [int(ref_date)])
                conn.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"ERROR - failed checking/deleting data: {str(e)}")
            pass

    for index, row_data in df_filtered.iterrows():
        columns = ', '.join(row_data.index)
        placeholders = ', '.join(['?' for _ in row_data.values])
        values = []

        for col, val in row_data.items():
            if pd.isna(val):
                values.append(None)
            elif col in ['CALC_DT', 'REF_DT']:
                values.append(int(val))
            elif col in ['STR_PRC', 'PROD_PRC']:
                values.append(float(val))
            else:
                values.append(str(val).strip())

        try:
            insert_query = f"INSERT INTO {table} ({columns}) VALUES ({placeholders})"
            cursor.execute(insert_query, values)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"ERROR - failed inserting new data: {str(e)}")
            pass
    conn.commit()


insert_data(cursor_test, conn_test, 'LIQTOOLDEV.RMSSTRPRI', df_filtered_test)
I have permission to write on this table ( i checked it) but still i get this error.
Plus i checked that the type of the values in the columns are all right (and they are)...  can you help me?

Docs here suggest that insert … with NC or insert … with NONE might help, but I know nothing about Db2.

Target table for the insert needs to be journaled if you are using commitment control
